# Flutter build ios bitcode problem, how to fix bitcode error

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

i try to build ios with my phone connected or flutter build ios i got this error

```
ld: '/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwvxvkkosgpgqncynmszqlholtde/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC/libBoringSSL-GRPC.a(BoringSSL-GRPC-dummy.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwvxvkkosgpgqncynmszqlholtde/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC/libBoringSSL-GRPC.a' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

if i run with simulator its work,
the problem occure when build whit pshyscal device connected or flutter build 
how to fix this ?

doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Users/user/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (4 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/User/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3, Build version 11C29
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • RIFAL’s iPhone • 8c498b6246bf8191b049a9253b87ff2604b85671 • ios • iOS 13.3

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar problem after installing one library which was dependent on the bitcode. Please change **Enable Bitcode** to all of the targets on the project **Pods** like in the image,

[image]

Comment: This fixed it for me. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I have to do this every time I want to build. There has to be a better way to do this and have it remember. Any thoughts?

Comment: Firstly, if the library that you are using enables bitcode by default you won't have to go through the trouble of setting it all the time.

And yes this is a frustrating but Flutter does not support bitcode as of this time, so the only better way I found is to avoid using a library which requires bitcode. I removed the extension that required bitcode in my project and used my own implementation so that I don't have to go through this hassle. This is the better way I found.

Comment: changing enable bitcode from YES to NO solved my issue.